# Why does this function have a saddle point ? $f(x)=3x^4+4x^3$

Tags: analysis, functions, derivatives

I have this function

$$f(x)=3x^4+4x^3$$

I have to find the extreme points. I did but just to be sure I put the problem in an online calculator and it said saddle point (0; 0). After some research I noticed that saddle points are common for two variables functions.. but I don't have a two variables function so why is there a saddle point ? 
Wolfram says it's an inflection point but Symbolab says it's a saddle point. Can someone enlighten me please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To my knowledge, the term "saddle point" only applies to multivariable cases. As such, this is just an inflection point, and symbolab is misusing the term.

Comment: Good to know, thanks.

Comment: How sad-dle :-(

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, a function of a single variable does not have a saddle point; rather, perhaps, you are alluding to a point of inflection---a point where the graph of the function changes concavity.

Candidates for such points are points for which $f''(x) = 0$.

Here, $f''(x) = 0$ occurs when $x = -1$ or $x = 0$.

To check if any of these yields a point of inflection, we check the concavity of the function over the intervals $(-\infty, -1)$, $(-1, 0)$ and $(0, \infty)$ by taking suitable test points a determining the sign of $f''(x)$.

Let's check, say, $x=-2$, $x = -1/2$ and $x=1$.

Observe, since $f''(-2)<0$, $f''(-1/2)>0$, and $f''(1)>0$, the graph of $f(x)$ changes concavity only through the candidate $x = -1$.

Hence, $(-1, -1)$ is the only point of inflection.